# Is it Possible to Change .Net Core Kendo Signalr Grid Transport-Client CRUD Names with Javascript

Tags: asp.net-core, kendo-ui, signalr, kendo-grid, crud

I have two `grid` on my page. They have `product data` from `order table`. Datasource type is `signalr`. I'm filtering them with some buttons according to `product category`.
Let me explain with example.

**Product Categories** (`MEAT`, `DESERT`)
**Products** `( Product-A, Product-B, Product-E, Product-F )` are in `MEAT` category 
**Products** `( Product-G, Product-H, Product-C, Product-D )` are in `DESERT` category 
**PRODUCT STATES** (`COOKING`, `COOKED`)

**`Grid1`** named `OrderProductTakenGrid` shows the `order products` for product state is `COOKING`
 Lets say data is `( Product-A, Product-B, Product-C, Product-D )`

**`Grid2`** named `OrderProductCookingGrid` shows the `order products` for product state is `COOKED`
 Lets say data is `( Product-E, Product-F, Product-G, Product-H )`

**Grid1 `OrderProductTakenGrid` code part :**

```
.Transport(tr =>{
      tr.Client(c => c
     .Read("readOrderProductsByOrderCategory")
     .Create("createOrderProductForCOOKING")
     .Update("updateOrderProductForCOOKING")
     .Destroy("destroyOrderProductForCOOKING"));
      tr.ParameterMap("datasourceParameterMapForCOOKING");
})
```

**Grid2 `OrderProductCookingGrid` code part :**

```
.Transport(tr =>{
      tr.Client(c => c
     .Read("readOrderProductsByOrderCategory")
     .Create("createOrderProductForCOOKED")
     .Update("updateOrderProductForCOOKED")
     .Destroy("destroyOrderProductForCOOKED"));
      tr.ParameterMap("datasourceParameterMapForCOOKED");
})
```

As you can see grids client methods named with **PRODUCT STATES** `COOKING` and `COOKED`

When i filter the grids according to `product category` lets say i filtered for `MEAT` category 
**Grid1** shows the data `( Product-A, Product-B )` 
**Grid2** shows the data `( Product-E, Product-F )` 
So far so good..

Lets say we send `product data` from `HUB` to `Grid Client Create method` : **`createOrderProductForCOOKED`**

```
Clients.Group("GroupNameDoesntMatter").SendAsync("createOrderProductForCOOKED", Product-D);
// Product-D is Product-D DATA
```

i see the `data` coming(being created) for `Grid2` even it has a filter with `MEAT` category and the `Product-D` belongs to the `DESERT` category.

**What i try is**

sends the product data from `Hub` to `Grid` with `productCategoryID` like this:

```
 var productCategoryID = getProductListItem.CategoryID;
 Clients.Group("GroupNameDoesntMatter").SendAsync("createOrderProductForCOOKED"+productCategoryID , Product-D);
```

and tried to change `Grids Client Method Names` while filtering the `grids` with simple button `javascript`

```
<script>

    $(".simpleFilterButton..").on("click", function() {

       var productCategoryID = ...;
       var Grid1 = $("#OrderProductTakenGrid").data("kendoGrid");
       Grid1.dataSource.transport.options.create.url = 
       "createOrderProductForCOOKING"+productCategoryID ;

       Grid1.read().then(function() {
          Grid1.refresh();
       });

       var Grid2 = $("#OrderProductCookingGrid").data("kendoGrid");
       Grid2.dataSource.transport.options.create.url = 
       "createOrderProductForCOOKED"+productCategoryID ;

       Grid2.read().then(function() {
          Grid2.refresh();
       });

    });

</script>
```

So even if change the `create urls` of `grids` with javascript they dont listen the `"createOrderProductForCOOKING"+productCategoryID` or `"createOrderProductForCOOKED"+productCategoryID` 
they still listen the previous methods `"createOrderProductForCOOKED"` or `"createOrderProductForCOOKING"`

I think i have some problem on changing the **`transport.options.create.url`** and i couldn't find any other solution on google to change it properly. Maybe it can not be.. but i'm open suggestions ..